# Como criar esse codigo: um botão clique aqui, apos clicar iniciar uma contagem de 5 segundos, e apos 5 segundos exibe conteudo oculto da div

Tags: javascript, html

um botão clique aqui, apos clicar iniciar uma contagem de 4 segundos, e apos 4 segundos é exibido conteúdo oculto da div

Neste código a baixo, aparece a div depois de 4 segundos, Porém eu quero um botão antes, que a pessoa clique, e após clicar, comece a contagem regressiva de 4 segundos e mostre na tela essa contagem, apos isso apareça o conteúdo da div

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

Conteudo normal fora da div<br><br>

<div ID="teste" style="display:none;">

Conteudo a ser exibido apos 4 segundos

</div>


<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
     setTimeout(carregar, 4000);
});

function carregar() {
    $('#teste').show();
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Crie o botão. Adicione o evento de `click` que gera o `setTimeout`. Use o `setInterval` para criar o cronômetro. Quer tentar?